# Referencing variables dynamically

Tags: variables, lua

I'm trying to dynamically reference a variable based on the return of a function in Lua. I have several variables and I can reference them all individually, but I am trying to clean up the code and find a way to dynamically reference them.

I have tried several different ways to get this to function and I'm honestly not sure it can be done at all. Everywhere I look to solve this issue I have found only instructions on creating dynamic variables instead of referencing variables dynamically.

```lua
varExample_1 = 3,
varExample_2 = 3,
varExample_3 = 5,
varExample_5 = 4,
varExample_4 = 2,

newVar = "varExample_" .. GetExampleType(call)

--or more specifically 

if 8 > varExample_ .. GetExampleType(call) then return false end
```

I'm attempting to get the variable values but with all examples, I can only get fo far as receiving the variable name as a string.

Comment: You'll make your life much easier by using table instead of global variables.

Comment: I am saving options to these variables so and using varExample_* for defaults.

Comment: I think `varExample[1]` is pretty readable too, so there's no reason to don't use table?

Comment: `if 8 > _G["varExample_"..GetExampleType(call)] then`

Comment: – Egor Skriptunoff
Tried that, that's what gives me "varExample_1" as a string, not the variable value.

Comment: Pay attention to `_G[...]` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, consider using table instead of global variables (always avoid them whenever possible):

```
local varExample = {}
varExample[1] = 3,
varExample[2] = 3,
varExample[3] = 5,
varExample[5] = 4,
varExample[4] = 2,
```

or even better

```
local varExample = {3, 3, 5, 4, 2}
```

and then

```
if 8 > varExample[GetExampleType(call)] then return false end
```

But you insist on using global variables, they can be accessed using `_G`:

```
if 8 > _G["varExample_"..GetExampleType(call)] then
```

Comment: Couldn't use as suggested because the variables are in an existing setting table and it would error each time I tried, however, it did give me the idea to use a secondary table and assign the existing variables into that table and then make the use that and that is working. Much appreciation for the help.